# webkit just cuts off decimals in css number ... how to workaround?

Tags: css, webkit, integer, width

when i use numbers with decimal in my css specs like this:

```
#UploadWrapper.OneRow #UploadList #UploadUl li div.imageDiv, #UploadWrapper.TwoRows #UploadList #UploadUl li div.imageDiv{
    width: 58.8px;
    height: 44px;
}
```

it seems, that Firefox uses the right number do calc the position but rounds the amount to thisplay it ... because it can only display it to native pixels.

Webkit browsers just takes the integer of the number (58) ...

How can i:

```
1. Force the Webkit browser to behave like FF?  ... or ...
2. Sepecify an other width, that only takes effect in webkit browsers? I already tried
   -webkit-width: but it didn't work ...
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do this elegantly. In generally it's best to see pixels as atomic units that can't be divided.

Solutions:

1. Find another way of positioning your elements. i.e. Use percentages or make the last column 1px shorter (or whatever your design needs to allow whole numbers to be used)
2. Use JS browser sniffing to add a class of "webkit" or similar to the body element and then use this to apply different style rules.

I'd suggest not using the second solution as it's probably unnecessary complicated.

Comment: Actually, seeing pixels as "atomic units that can't be divided" is something that breaks as soon as you're on an iPhone 4 or as soon as the user zooms....  But yes, I agree there is no good workaround for WebKit's "we'll just round all lengths to integer pixels at compute time" brokenness.